# 196-Algorithm Program

Tags: python, performance, palindrome

Attempting to see whether using 196 as `a` respectively in my program will have a result or not, I made a simple function to test it. Now the [196-Algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/196-Algorithm.html) requires this:

- Take any positive integer with at least two digits, `a`
- Take `a` and reverse it (for example 23 becomes 32)
- Now add the new number to `a`
- Repeat the process until the `a` is a palindrome (when reversed, a palindrome's value should still be the same)

This is my function:

```
def one_nine_six_algorithm(a):
    b = a
    if a > 9:
        while str(b)[::-1] != str(b):
            c = str(b)[::-1]
            b += int(c)
        return b
```

In this program, I literally did how do the algorithm. The integer, `a`, is taken in and checked that it is a positive, two-digit number. Then, the algorithm is run in the `while` loop, where `b` is the new/current value of `a` and `c` is basically `b` reversed but as a string  in able to use `[::-1]`. Then `c` as an integer (`int(c)`) is added to `b` and is continued until `b` is a palindrome (checked in the `while` line). Then it returns `b`, which is used for whatever reason I need it for.

Now for complicated integers, this might go through a lot of loops and take a lot of time to finish. Is there a more efficient way to improve my program in terms of speed and readability?

Comment: For what it's worth, this question/algorithm (and the oddity of 196 when reversed and added this way) has been around a *long* time. Just for example, it was in the inaugaral issue of one of the first magazines for small computers: [Creative Computing](https://archive.org/stream/CreativeComputingv01n02JanFeb1975/Creative_Computing_v01n02_Jan-Feb_1975#page/n11/mode/2up)

Comment: `a > 9` does not test for a **two**-digit number, it tests that the number has **more than one** digit. Is that a flaw in your description of the algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why bother renaming `a` to `b`?

This function would be more useful as a generator, because you will be interested in finding the next number in the sequence.  That is, you should `yield` rather than `return` the result.

You wrote `str(b)` three times.  Once would be better, but that would still be once too many, if you care about performance.  Keep in mind that stringifying a number involves allocating an object, some buffer space, some arithmetic, and translation to ASCII behind the scenes.  A function to compute the reversed integer yourself, even if it involves writing more code, should be faster.